# On Linux, how do I the check CPU affinity of a process and its threads?

Tags: linux

On Linux, how do I the check CPU affinity of a process and its threads?

Comment: Why are you doing this? For a multithreaded process where you care about affinity, couldn't you use `taskset` to execute or leverage cgroups so the children all respect the affinities?

Comment: @ewwhite I'm doing this to _check_ the affinity after setting them.  I'm not asking about _how_ or _why_ to set the affinity.

Comment: O I C... Actually, not really. You haven't explained why you're looking for this info.

Comment: @ewwhite The _why_ is to verify a program's threads have affinity set as expected.  These are mostly-independent processing threads on a multicore machine.

Answer (score 14):

It's pretty simple.  **Gather the all process id and thread ids then call program [`taskset`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html).**  Like,

```
taskset -cp 2
taskset -cp 4
…
```

#### print all by process name

`taskset` has the `--all-tasks` optional argument

```
taskset --all-tasks -p $(pgrep java)
```

For some processes, the `--all-tasks` doesn't appear to print all of the child processes (in my testing, it didn't print child processes for `kthreadd`, I'm not sure why that is).

#### print all by process name helper script

Here is a short Linux shell script to print CPU affinity for a process by name and all of it's child threads.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

pname=${1:-kthreadd}  # default to 'kthreadd'
for pid in $(pgrep "${pname}"); do
    echo "PID: ${pid} (${pname})"
    for tid in $(pgrep -P "${pid}" | tr '\n' ' '); do
        taskset -cp "${tid}"
    done
done
```

Outputs

```
PID: 2 (kthreadd)
pid 4's current affinity list: 0
pid 6's current affinity list: 0
pid 7's current affinity list: 0
pid 8's current affinity list: 0
…
```

Tested on Ubuntu 12, bash 4.